# How to re-read a modified file with elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use (find-file-noselect "filename"),but it always ask"File changed. Reread from disk?" And I have to answer yes.
How can it reread without asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from Lindydancer answer `auto-revert-mode` is a good for automatically reverting a buffer if the file is changed by external process. and there is also `revert-file` for which I have a key binding

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (revert-buffer t t t)
                                (message "buffer is reverted")))
```

Answer (score 6):

`find-file-noselect` has an optional parameter `nowarn` that seems to suppress questions like this, try:

```
(find-file-noselect "filename" t)
```